# Slow site...understanding google chrome network results

Tags: php, performance, google-chrome, drupal-7

Im experiencing a really slow site. It takes a lot of time before the images on the frontpage shows up and i have a high load time. This is an image from the results from loading the frontpage with the network tab open. I should mention that this problem does not occur on my localhost (identical duplicate of the site). Can anyone give me any pointers on where to look? Can it be a server issue or is it most likely just something wrong with the backend logic?

[image]

Deeply appreciate any help!

Comment: threre are a lot of speed testing\load tools on the web

Comment: Test your website with: `http://gtmetrix.com`, seems you have very poor server hosting

Comment: You ask *understanding Google Chrome network results* - which is a good question, but then go on to ask for random advise about server issue, etc.  The google chrome results tell you a lot, so why don't you focus on that part of your question.  (Images and other assets will load FAST on localhost - so the fact that you have 115 requests is telling - that's a lot of requests)

Comment: Waiting 3sec for a 13KB static image isn't a normal thing ( if you have good network connection )

Answer (score 1):

1) you can create image style to reduce the image size
2) you can also use boots module to speed up site
3) or Please check your server response time if there is any issue persent